# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread - fs->in_exec clone() and execve() clash?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I am occasionally experiencing :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:691)
```

I've read a lot about this, and I don't believe I am hitting a real limit, in terms of
physical memory, virtual memory (64 bit JVM), thread limit, process limit or file descriptors.

In fact, I'm not even sure this is in any way related to the fact the processes that I notice being impacted are Java processes.

My suspicion is that this is a problem in the Linux kernel, or possibly depending on how it is argued, a problem in the Java JVM, or pthread_create().

The machine I see this on is a monster: 64 processors, 512GB RAM (70GB free).
Its running RHES 5.11 (Tikanga) 2.6.18-402.el5 x86_64.
Limits are set like this

```
bash-3.2$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
65536
bash-3.2$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
8257699

bash-3.2$ /sbin/sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 62220      0       1048576

bash-3.2$ /sbin/sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 1048576

bash-3.2$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 4128849
max locked memory   (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4128849
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Many users use this computer, and thus far, only two of them (me and one other) have reported the problem. The common thing about these users are that the impacted processes will be periodically creating Java threads
which run for a short while and then stop, and that also, there will be other processes periodically and regularly scheduled under the same userid. The victim Java process itself isn't exec-ing any other processes itself.

In my case, the Java process regularly establishes JMX connections, uses them, then closes them, and this involves thread creation in the background (which is not under my control, so I can't pool it). The other activity is a looping shell script that runs some processes, then sleeps, then repeats. Numbers of processes, numbers of threads per process, memory use, file descriptor use, etc..., are all well within limits.

In the implementation of fork.c, there are various reasons why EAGAIN can be returned, mostly resource or security reasons (which I am finding difficult to believe in this case), and also one relating to copy_fs and fs->in_exec.
in_exec can apparently be set when there is an unsafe execve, in check_unsafe_execve(), depending on the use of the shared struct fs_struct (which I don't quite understand, see comments at the end).

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e66eded8309ebf679d3d3c1f5820d1f2ca332c71/kernel/fork.c

In essence, it seems as if there is some race-condition or unfortunate timing alignment between clone() processing and execve() processing which can cause clone() to return EAGAIN.
To me, this seems wrong, as there isn't actually a resource limit reached, and aren't "Too many processes" per man page for clone().

There is discussion online about whether this behaviour is needed or correct.
http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0905.0/02309.html

If the argument is that if a well behaved program should retry later if it receives EAGAIN from clone(), well, this is problematic, as how is a program to differentiate between an EAGAIN caused by in_exec (which it would want to retry) and a genuine resource shortage (which perhaps it wouldn't want to keep retrying for a very long time for).

I've seen the exception on Java 7 and Java 8, and I don't think the version matters, so looking at any old OpenJDK source version, I can see no retry happens (os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp).

Also, from strace, I can see the JVM issuing the clone(), receiving the EAGAIN, and then dying ...

```
1454948661.318678 clone(
    child_stack=0x2b6297dc5250,
    flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_
    parent_tidptr=0x2b6297dc59d0,
    tls=0x2b6297dc5940, child_tidptr=0x2b6297dc59d0
    ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavaiable)
```

At this point I am not sure that I am looking at the right Linux kernel source for the kernel being used.
I also don't understand what the fs_struct is for, and how it might be shared between threads and processes.
So having explored limits, I am investigating this other possibility because it is what is left.

If I am right, what would it take to deliberately cause the problem.
I've tried writing programs that start lots of pthreads and fork and execve short lived processes so as to increase the chance of clone() occurring in Java at the same time as execve(). I've tried a few variations, but I am not sure I've managed to get the right combination of events, or lucky.
This is probably because I don't fully appreciate what it means to get an "unsafe" execve().

What is fs_struct, when might it be shared, how do I influence that?

Does what I am suggesting make sense?

Any advice on how to prove/disprove my suspicion?

Comment: I think you need more information about thread creation in the affected programs first - specifically how many threads are in existence at the time that the OOM condition occurs? Are you sure you're not simply hitting the OS limits of threads-per-process, threads-per-user, stack-space etc?

Comment: When we have encountered this problem it has always been caused by hitting the `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` limit. Are you 100% sure you are not hitting this? You should at least count the number of threads live on your system when you encounter the problem. Running `ps -eL| wc -l` should show you total number of threads on the system.

Comment: Comfortably within limits. Never seen total number of threads above 30000, and pid_max is 65536.

Comment: What are your `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio` settings?  You might want to try `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to 1 (always overcommit) to see if your issue goes away.  If it does go away, you probably should go back to your initial settings and add more swap space.

Comment: 0 and 50 respectively, but I am not in a position to change these settings.